# What character could be use to identify personal powershell scripts?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

In his brilliant talk [Activation Energy](https://youtu.be/pybtvFFRYFs?si=uAtbE2mRzztUnoes), Brandon Rhodes recommend starting all your scripts with a comma character (`,`) so they are easy to search with the shell autocomplete.

In the Linux context it might work, but on Windows Powershell (7), starting a script name with `,myscript.psy` don't seems to be recognized by the autocomplete (typing `,` +`TAB` won't do anything).

What character could be used to achieve the same purpose?
How do you identify your script?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "*(typing , +TAB won't do anything)*". On my system it autocompletes the name and even adds a `&` at the front. ‍♂️

Comment: Interesting, maybe it's a limitation of the terminal? Are you using the Windows Terminal ?

Comment: why use script files when you can have functions loaded in your session, i.e. at startup with your `$profile` ? I only see disadvantages on using script files vs loaded functions for powershell specifically.

Comment: @gberth It doesn't matter what I use. It works everywhere. ‍♂️

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the problem is that inside `$profile` you define you script with function, not file name. Therefore you can't use special character.

Comment: @Olaf I'm saying that it does not work on my machine.

Comment: That's the point, you don't need any special character on your scripts. Function discovery works perfectly fine, when loaded with your profile you can just `My-Func<TAB>`

Comment: @Olaf, it only works for scripts in the _current directory_, not for those discoverable by name only via `$env:PATH`.

Comment: @mklement0 That's what I thought it was about. ‍♂️ 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're talking about scripts located in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`, i.e scripts you can call *by name only*, from any working directory.

- By contrast, scripts located in the *current* directory *can* be tab-completed with `,` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (e.g., tab-completing script `,foo.ps1` in the current directory turns into `& '.\,foo.ps1'` (the quoting is necessary due to the nonstandard name, and the quoting in turn requires use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)).

For `$env:PATH`-based scripts `,` does *not* work, as you've experienced, and the only alternatives I can think of are:

- `_`
- `^`

At least on an English keyboard, neither is as convenient to type as `,` due to requiring leaving the home row of the keyboard and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit sad about `,` not working, but `_` should do the trick.